# Visual leak detector output analysis: not able to decode what the result on output screen means

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory-leaks

While executing my Visual C++ program on Visual Studio 10.0 with Visual Leak Detector I get the following result on output screen:

```
{359} normal block at 0x00000000012FFF30, 16 bytes long
 Data: <                > D8 0F 94 E4 F7 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

This is one of the lines of the output..If some1 can plz tell me how to analyze this or e1 what it means it would b a great help.Also at the starting of the leaks I also get these lines:

```
 Call Stack:
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory (36): Dual OS.exe!std::_Allocate<std::_Container_proxy> + 0x22 bytes
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory (188): Dual OS.exe!std::allocator<std::_Container_proxy>::allocate
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring (469): Dual OS.exe!std::_String_val<char,std::allocator<char> >::_String_val<char,std::allocator<char> > + 0xF bytes
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring (550): Dual OS.exe!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > + 0x33 bytes
    c:\users\parthkumars\desktop\dualos\duos\duosdlg.cpp (385): Dual OS.exe!CDUOSDlg::CDUOSDlg + 0xA2 bytes
    c:\users\parthkumars\desktop\dualos\duos\duos.cpp (39): Dual OS.exe!`dynamic initializer for 'dlg'' + 0x12 bytes
    0x0000000014510E94 (File and line number not available): (Module name unavailable)!(Function name unavailable)
  Data:
    D0 0C 94 E4    F7 07 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........


---------- Block 2 at 0x00000000012FFA40: 16 bytes ----------
  Call Stack:
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory (36): Dual OS.exe!std::_Allocate<std::_Container_proxy> + 0x22 bytes
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory (188): Dual OS.exe!std::allocator<std::_Container_proxy>::allocate
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector (442): Dual OS.exe!std::_Vector_val<std::pair<unsigned long,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned long,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > > >::_Vector_val<std::pair<unsign + 0xF bytes
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector (507): Dual OS.exe!std::vector<std::pair<unsigned long,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned long,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > > >::vector<std::pair<unsigned long,st + 0x33 bytes
    c:\users\parthkumars\desktop\dualos\duos\eventdispatcher.h (19): Dual OS.exe!CEventDispatcher::CEventDispatcher + 0x3D bytes
    c:\users\parthkumars\desktop\dualos\duos\duosdlg.cpp (385): Dual OS.exe!CDUOSDlg::CDUOSDlg + 0x149 bytes
    c:\users\parthkumars\desktop\dualos\duos\duos.cpp (39): Dual OS.exe!`dynamic initializer for 'dlg'' + 0x12 bytes
    0x0000000014510E94 (File and line number not available): (Module name unavailable)!(Function name unavailable)
  Data:
    88 0D 94 E4    F7 07 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
```

Answer (score 0):

The output basically tells you that your program allocated some memory, but it did not free it before terminating.

The first output tells you how much and what data is contained in the memory.

The call stack tells you where the memory was allocated.

Comment: yeah I figured it out a few hours ago.. Thank You nyways..thnx a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the CEventDispatcher constructor, you should find a new of a std::vector of pair for which there is now delete (the correct place to put it can be the dtor)

for me the important in that repot is the call stack, it show the allocation point and later if you masterize debugger you will be able to use function address and offset!

Comment: Well seems a bit too much as I am a new user of VLD..but still there are a few leaks (pointers) whose location is too difficult to reach..well that's something I have to work on..Thank You nyways!!